# function not returning list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple script to generate UK lottery numbers (7 numbers, 1 to 49 inclusive).
My code has a function that generates 7 random numbers into a list, runs set on the list removing duplicate numbers, checks if there are still 7 members in the list, and if not the function calls itself to generate 7 new numbers.

However, when the function calls itself it does not return the list.

I'd appreciate knowing what I'm doing wrong here.

```
from random import randint

def lotto():

    l = []
    for r in range(1,8):
        l.append(randint(1,49))

    print "DEBUG: l=", l
    print "DEBUG: set(l)=", set(l), len(set(l))

    if(len(set(l)) !=7):
        lotto()
    else:
        print "Before return l, l = ", l
        return l

def main():
    numbers = lotto()
    print numbers
```

Here is a sample run that does not work correctly:

```
DEBUG: l= [44, 32, 12, 12, 33, 16, 31]
DEBUG: set(l)= set([32, 33, 44, 12, 16, 31]) 6
DEBUG: l= [46, 20, 10, 24, 16, 35, 44]
DEBUG: set(l)= set([35, 10, 44, 46, 16, 20, 24]) 7
Before return l, l =  [46, 20, 10, 24, 16, 35, 44]
None
```

And a sample run that does work correctly:

```
DEBUG: l= [20, 5, 21, 37, 10, 44, 38]
DEBUG: set(l)= set([37, 38, 10, 44, 20, 21, 5]) 7
Before return l, l =  [20, 5, 21, 37, 10, 44, 38]
[20, 5, 21, 37, 10, 44, 38]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning the result of the recursive call.

```
if(len(set(l)) !=7):
    return lotto()
```

Comment: Thank you all of you. That has done the trick. I was (obviously) totally unaware of the necessity to have lotto() in a return statement, and to be honest I'm still not too sure why! But it is the way. Thanks again.

Comment: To show that the question as been resolved, mark his answer as accepted by pressing the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Lanaru - I did, but it told me I had to wait x mins before I could mark it as resolved.

Comment: @nickl "I'm still not too sure why"  If you don't return the value returned from the call to lotto, the first instance of the function call (after all the recursion is done) will fall out of the `if: else:` block and return nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive call

```
lotto()
```

does not actually return the value returned by `lotto()`.  You'd need to use

```
return lotto()
```

instead.  (Note that instead of the tail-recursive call, a loop would be preferable.)

That said, there is a much easier solution to your actual problem, namely [`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample).  Python2.x version:

```
import random
print random.sample(xrange(1, 50), 7)
```

Python 3.x version:

```
import random
print(random.sample(range(1, 50), 7))
```

Comment: That certainly does make things easier, I will use that sample method, many thanks.